# How to save cookies in shared preferences in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http

How to save cookies in shared preferences in iOS?
And How can I extract it later?
I want to save the cookie from **HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies** into user defaults and then extract later
Please answer in Swift 3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code:

**Store:**

```
func storeCookies() {
    let cookiesStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let serverBaseUrl = "http://example.com"
    var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()

    for cookie in cookiesStorage.cookies(for: NSURL(string: serverBaseUrl)! as URL)! {
        cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
    }

    userDefaults.set(cookieDict, forKey: "cookiesKey")
}
```

**Retrieve:**

```
func restoreCookies() {
    let cookiesStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let cookieDictionary = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "cookiesKey") {

        for (_, cookieProperties) in cookieDictionary {
            if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] ) {
                cookiesStorage.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Splendid, wurks!

Comment: This helped me so much. I'm manually saving all NEW cookies the server response from my wkwebview is getting. Then loading them manually on startup of my wkwebview. I needed this after I was required to use WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent() to make SSO work.

Answer (score 4):

My solution with Swift 4, WKWebView & iOS 11. Worked for me in a case where PHPSESSID pushed from the server was not being saved across runs of the app, with user already logged in so the sesssion should just continue. With some blurb to help debugging:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var html: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        html.navigationDelegate = self
        retrieve_cookies()
    }

    func opensite()
    {
        let addr = "https://thesite.com/bla/bla"
        let url = URL(string: addr)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        html.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let ds = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        let cookies = ds.httpCookieStore
        cookies.getAllCookies { (cookies: [HTTPCookie]) in
            for cookie in cookies {
                NSLog("Known cookie at load: \(cookie.name)")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Starting to load")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        NSLog("** Error" + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        NSLog("Load finished")
        let ds = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        let cookies = ds.httpCookieStore
        cookies.getAllCookies { (cookies: [HTTPCookie]) in
            var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()
            for cookie in cookies {
                NSLog("Saved cookie: \(cookie.name)")
                cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(cookieDict, forKey: "cookiez")
        }
    }

    func retrieve_cookies()
    {
        let ds = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        let cookies = ds.httpCookieStore
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let cookieDict = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "cookiez") {
            NSLog("Retrieving cookies")
            var cookies_left = 0
            for (_, cookieProperties) in cookieDict {
                if let _ = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] ) {
                    cookies_left += 1
                }
            }
            for (_, cookieProperties) in cookieDict {
                if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] ) {
                    cookies.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: {
                        cookies_left -= 1
                        NSLog("Retrieved cookie, \(cookies_left) to go")
                        if cookies_left == 0 {
                            self.opensite()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("No saved cookies")
            opensite()
        }
    }
```