# Swift : Set custom cookies for Safari app

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, httpcookie

I have iOS application, that you need to login to, and view some user data...
For some extra edit, I have url link to page, where can user set some special properties,... but it is really annoying for users to login inside page, if they are already logged in application.

For this reason I need to store custom cookies in HTTPCookieStorage, so that when user navigate to the page, authentication cookies would be set for him.

How to create custom cookie with key-value, and store it so that Safari will use it when user navigate to my page?

EDIT

---

I will provide more information to better understand my situation.

I have one button inside my app.

After clicking to this button, I call API to get valid token. 
After receiving token, I need to store this token as cookies. The "server" way of doing this would be

```
localStorage.setItem('token', this.token)
```

After I would store this token into HTTPCookieStorage, I will open my page.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(myURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                        print("Url open")
                    })
```

In page on myURL, the application look for a token cookies. If cookies exist it open web app, else it presents login page.

So my goal is to prevent opening login page.

Answer (score 0):

**Store your cookies:**

```
func storeCookies() {
    let cookiesStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let serverBaseUrl = "http://example.com"
    var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()

    for cookie in cookiesStorage.cookies(for: NSURL(string: serverBaseUrl)! as URL)! {
        cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
    }

    userDefaults.set(cookieDict, forKey: "cookiesKey")
}
```

**Retrieve:**

```
func restoreCookies() {
    let cookiesStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let cookieDictionary = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "cookiesKey") {

        for (_, cookieProperties) in cookieDictionary {
            if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] ) {
                cookiesStorage.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why [repeat your previous identical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43980792/1187415)? If you think that the question has been asked and answered before then you can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answer my question? Your code only stored already set cookies into userDefaults, and then back from user defaults to cookiesStorage. I don't see where I can add new custom cookie?

Comment: @MartinR It's because sometimes owner of the post deletes the question. Then the answer will no longer be accessible.

Comment: Okay didn't know that thing

Comment: I add edit, so it is maybe more clear what I have in mind.